# How to set class attribute with await in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

How can I define a class with `await` in the constructor or class body?

For example what I want:

```py
import asyncio

# some code


class Foo(object):

    async def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)

foo = Foo(settings)
# it raises:
# TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'
```

or example with class body attribute:

```py
class Foo(object):

    self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)  # Sure it raises syntax Error

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

foo = Foo(settings)
```

My solution (But I would like to see a more elegant way)

```py
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    async def init(self):
        self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)

foo = Foo(settings)
await foo.init()
```

Comment: You might have some luck with `__new__`, although it might not be elegant

Comment: I don't have experience with 3.5, and in other languages this wouldn't work because of the viral nature of async/await, but have you tried defining an async function like `_pool_init(dsn)` and then calling it from `__init__`? It would preserve the init-in-constructor appearance.

Comment: If you use curio: https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#curio.meta.AsyncObject

Comment: use `@classmethod`  it's an alternate constructor. put the async work there; then in `__init__`, just set the `self` attributes

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Most magic methods aren't designed to work with `async def`/`await` - in general, you should only be using `await` inside the dedicated asynchronous magic methods - `__aiter__`, `__anext__`, `__aenter__`, and `__aexit__`. Using it inside other magic methods either won't work at all, as is the case with `__init__` (unless you use some tricks described in other answers here), or will force you to always use whatever triggers the magic method call in an asynchronous context.

Existing `asyncio` libraries tend to deal with this in one of two ways: First, I've seen the factory pattern used ([`asyncio-redis`](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/asyncio-redis/blob/master/asyncio_redis/pool.py#L27), for example):

```
import asyncio

dsn = "..."

class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, settings):
        self = cls()
        self.settings = settings
        self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)
        return self

async def main(settings):
    settings = "..."
    foo = await Foo.create(settings)
```

Other libraries use a top-level coroutine function that creates the object, rather than a factory method:

```
import asyncio

dsn = "..."

async def create_foo(settings):
    foo = Foo(settings)
    await foo._init()
    return foo

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    async def _init(self):
        self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)

async def main():
    settings = "..."
    foo = await create_foo(settings)
```

The `create_pool` function from `aiopg` that you want to call in `__init__` is actually using this exact pattern.

This at least addresses the `__init__` issue. I haven't seen class variables that make asynchronous calls in the wild that I can recall, so I don't know that any well-established patterns have emerged.

Comment: Thanks @dano, I like the asyncio-redis approach and I am trying to copy it for my code. My problem is that I'd need to inherit Foo in another class. I am used to inheriting classes with super().__init__(*parent_args, **parent_kwargs), but I can't figure out how to both init the parent and call the factory method. Doing super().__init__() and then Parent.create() does not work

Comment: @dano, you should fix up your first example code block here. `Foo.create` is a `classmethod` but it is not using `cls`. That `self = Foo()` should be `self = cls()`.

Comment: @bulletmark done

Answer (score 100):

Another way to do this, for funsies:

```
class aobject(object):
    """Inheriting this class allows you to define an async __init__.

    So you can create objects by doing something like `await MyClass(params)`
    """
    async def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        await instance.__init__(*a, **kw)
        return instance

    async def __init__(self):
        pass

#With non async super classes

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2
        super().__init__()

class C(B, aobject):
    async def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.c=3

#With async super classes

class D(aobject):
    async def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class E(D):
    async def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2
        await super().__init__(1)

# Overriding __new__

class F(aobject):
    async def __new__(cls):
        print(cls)
        return await super().__new__(cls)

    async def __init__(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.f = 6

async def main():
    e = await E()
    print(e.b) # 2
    print(e.a) # 1

    c = await C()
    print(c.a) # 1
    print(c.b) # 2
    print(c.c) # 3

    f = await F() # Prints F class
    print(f.f) # 6

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This is currently the most clear and understandable implementation in my opinion. I really like how intuitively extensible it is. I was worried it would be necessary to delve into metaclasses.

Comment: This doesn't have correct `__init__` semantics if `super().__new__(cls)` returns a pre-existing instance - normally, this would skip `__init__`, but your code not.

Comment: Hmm, per `object.__new__` documentation, `__init__` should only be invoked if `isinstance(instance, cls)` ? This seems somewhat unclear to me... But I don't see the semantics you claim anywhere...

Comment: Thinking about this more, if you override `__new__` to return a pre-existing object, that new would need to be the outermost to make any sense, since other implementations of `__new__` would have no general way of knowing if you're returning a new uninitialized instance or not.

Comment: Can @tankobot or Khazhyk or someone help explain this magic? Why does that `async __new__(...)` magically makes `async __init__(...)` valid?

Comment: @RayLuo because the `__new__` method `await`s `__init__`, and there's nothing preventing you from defining any of these magic methods as async

Comment: @khazhyk Well, there IS definitely something preventing you from defining `async def __init__(...)`, as showed by the OP, and I believe that `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'` exception is hardcoded inside Python and could not be bypassed. So I tried to understand how an `async def __new__(...)` made a difference. Now my understanding is that, your `async def __new__(...)` (ab)use the characteristic of "if `__new__()` does not return an instance of cls, then `__init__()` will not be invoked". Your new `__new__()` returns a coroutine, not a cls. That's why. Clever hack!

Comment: @RayLuo ha, interesting! I stumbled past that then, learned something new today :)

Comment: @khazhyk technically you don't need to make any magic methods async, you just need `__new__` to return an `Awaitable` instead of an instance.  So you can make an async class method helper and use that inside `__new__` if you wanted. You can always just call an async method without await, it returns a coroutine. Then you return the coroutine from `__new__` and let someone else await it to get the instance.

Answer (score 45):

Better yet you can do something like this, which is very easy:

```py
import asyncio

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    async def async_init(self):
        await create_pool(dsn)

    def __await__(self):
        return self.async_init().__await__()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
foo = loop.run_until_complete(Foo(settings))
```

Basically what happens here is `__init__()`  gets called first as usual. Then `__await__()` gets called which then awaits `async_init()`.

Comment: I like this simple and straight design for initialize a async class but I think you forget to write `return self` in `async_init()` method

Comment: This is probably the best solution, if you want to use base classes or class decorators that rely on standard `__new__()` and `__init__()`. E.g. the popular dataclasses.
The only issue I can see is that the instance can be awaited more than once, calling the `__await__()` more than once. But somebody may intentionally want this. Or if it is an issue, it can be prevented by a flag.

Comment: `async def __aenter__(self): return await self` is missing, to make this usable as an async context manager like `async with Foo() as foo: foo.bar()`

Answer (score 27):

I would recommend a separate factory method. It's safe and straightforward. However, if you insist on a `async` version of `__init__()`, here's an example:

```
def asyncinit(cls):
    __new__ = cls.__new__

    async def init(obj, *arg, **kwarg):
        await obj.__init__(*arg, **kwarg)
        return obj

    def new(cls, *arg, **kwarg):
        obj = __new__(cls, *arg, **kwarg)
        coro = init(obj, *arg, **kwarg)
        #coro.__init__ = lambda *_1, **_2: None
        return coro

    cls.__new__ = new
    return cls
```

**Usage:**

```
@asyncinit
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        '''Do nothing. Just for test purpose.'''
        print(cls)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    async def __init__(self):
        self.initialized = True
```

```
async def f():
    print((await Foo()).initialized)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(f())
```

**Output:**

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>
True
```

**Explanation:**

Your class construction must return a `coroutine` object instead of its own instance.

Comment: Couldn't you name your `new` `__new__` and use `super` (likewise for `__init__`, i.e. just let the client override that) instead?

Answer (score 11):

The AsyncObj class with `__ainit__` "async-constructor":

```
class AsyncObj:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Standard constructor used for arguments pass
        Do not override. Use __ainit__ instead
        """
        self.__storedargs = args, kwargs
        self.async_initialized = False

    async def __ainit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Async constructor, you should implement this """

    async def __initobj(self):
        """ Crutch used for __await__ after spawning """
        assert not self.async_initialized
        self.async_initialized = True
        await self.__ainit__(*self.__storedargs[0], **self.__storedargs[1])  # pass the parameters to __ainit__ that passed to __init__
        return self

    def __await__(self):
        return self.__initobj().__await__()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        assert asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(cls.__ainit__)  # __ainit__ must be async

    @property
    def async_state(self):
        if not self.async_initialized:
            return "[initialization pending]"
        return "[initialization done and successful]"
```

Here is example of "async class":

```
class MyAsyncObject(AsyncObj):
    async def __ainit__(self, param1, param2=0):
        print("hello!", param1, param2)
        # go something async, e.g. go to db
```

Usage:

```
async def example():
    my_obj = await MyAsyncObject("test", 123)
```

Answer (score 8):

[Almost] canonical answer by @ojii

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    settings: Settings
    pool: Pool

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, settings: Settings, dsn):
        return cls(settings, await create_pool(dsn))
```

Comment: `dataclasses` for the win! so easy.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to show a much easier way of initiating coroutine based method within the `__init__` method.

```
import asyncio


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
        self.pool = loop.run_until_complete(create_pool(dsn))

foo = Foo(settings)
```

Important point to be noted is:

- This makes the async code work as sync(blocking)
- This is not the best way to run async code, but when it comes to only initiation via a sync method eg:  `__init__` it will be a good fit.
- After initiation, you can run the async methods from the object with await. i.e `await foo.pool.get(value)`
- Do not try to initiate via an `await` call you will get `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

Comment: in other words, this solution works except anywhere you'd actually want to use it, i.e. when the loop is already running. And what about anyio / trio?

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs I dont know much about trio. In case of running loop, you can push this co-routine as a task and wait for it to be completed.

Answer (score 4):

Vishnu shettigar's answer is so far the simplest, except that his `async_init` method doesn't return the object itself so `foo` isn't assigned a `Foo` instance. As for OP's purpose, the most elegant way to construct the class IMHO is

```
import asyncio

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    def __await__(self):
        self.pool = asyncio.create_task(create_pool(dsn))
        yield from self.pool
        self.pool = self.pool.result()
        return self
```

To initialize the object, do the following

```
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    foo = loop.run_until_complete(Foo(settings))
```

Or

```
async def main():
    foo = await Foo(settings)
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately allows a spurious "await object" to actually run, which is not what you'd intend to do if you're writing resilient programs. Alternately if I do want to add an `__await__` method to the class, this solution prevents me from doing that.

Comment: @Matthias, could you tell another use of await magic method in the class? I can only see `c = await C()`, and this is it.

Comment: The problem arises if you then mistakenly write "await c" instead of "await c.wait()" or similar. No checker will report that error. At minimum I'd throw an error if `self.pool` already exists.

Answer (score 2):

we could convert the async call to sync call by running the async code manually through `asyncio.run()`

```py
class Foo:
    async def __ainit__(self, param):
        self._member = await some_async_func(param)

    def __init__(self, param):
        asyncio.run(self.__ainit__(param))
```

Comment: No you can't. (a) nobody said you're using asyncio, (b) calling asyncio.run` recursively doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this mixin:

```
import asyncio


class AsyncMixin:
    """Adds an async_init method to an object which is called when the
    object is awaited.
    Typically the idiom obj = await Object()
    provides the synchronous __init__() and async async_init() calls"""

    async def async_init(self):
        """If an AsyncMixin object is created in an async context (ie await
        Object() then the __init__ method is non-async as normal but
        the async_init() method is called immediately by the
        __await__() magic method.
        """
        pass

    async def _async_init(self):
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.async_init())
        await task
        return self

    def __await__(self):
        return self._async_init().__await__()
    pass
```

So the OP's solution becomes:

```
class Foo(object, AsyncMixin):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    async def async_init(self):
        self.pool = await create_pool(dsn)

foo = await Foo(settings)
```

Which I think is quite elegant

Answer (score 2):

Just for records, this could also be achieved by creating a custom metaclass and overriding `__call__` method. When you put parenthesis in front of the name of a class, you're actually calling this method. This is much like the solution suggested by @khazhyk, except you interrupt the procedure earlier and also no need to override `__new__`.

```py
# interpreter version: 3.10
import asyncio


class AsyncInit(type):
    async def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        await instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance


class A(metaclass=AsyncInit):
    async def __init__(self, n):
        print(f"{n=} - giving the control back to event loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("initialization finished")


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[A(i) for i in range(1, 5)])


asyncio.run(main())
```

output:

```
n=1 - giving the control back to event loop
n=2 - giving the control back to event loop
n=3 - giving the control back to event loop
n=4 - giving the control back to event loop
initialization finished
initialization finished
initialization finished
initialization finished
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone can try：
https://pypi.org/project/asyncinit/

- pip install asyncinit

```py
from asyncinit import asyncinit

@asyncinit
class MyClass:
    async def __init__(self, param):
        self.val = await self.deferredFn(param)

    async def deferredFn(self, x):
        # ...
        return x + 2

obj = await MyClass(42)
assert obj.val == 44
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also use `AwaitLoader` from:
https://pypi.org/project/async-property/

From the docs:

> `AwaitLoader` will call await `instance.load()`, if it exists, before loading properties.

Answer (score 0):

another trick to override an existing class with sync init and async methods

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# lazy async init
# this only works if all methods are async

import asyncio

class LazyAsyncReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "ainit ..."
        self._ainit_done = False
    async def __ainit__(self):
        self.value = "ainit done"
        self._ainit_done = True
    async def read(self):
        if not self._ainit_done:
            await self.__ainit__()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        return self.value

# alternative: unswitch the read function by monkeypatching
class LazyAsyncReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "ainit ..."
    async def __ainit__(self):
        self.value = "ainit done"
    async def read(self, *a, **k):
        await self.__ainit__()
        self.read = self._read_ainit_done
        return await self._read_ainit_done(*a, **k)
    async def _read_ainit_done(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        return self.value

async def main():
    # sync init
    reader = LazyAsyncReader()
    # async method
    res = await reader.read()
    print(res)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in Python 3.9

```
from aiobotocore.session import AioSession
import asyncio




class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self):
        asyncio.run(self.async_init())
        print(self.s3)

    async def async_init(self):
        self.s3 = await AioSession().create_client('s3').__aenter__()
```

Comment: No it doesn't. You can't just nest `asyncio.run` calls. Also what if I'm using anyio ??

Comment: I just did. what's up!