# Using async await in Python __init__ method

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I am writing a class and want to use an async function in the `__init__` method to set up some variables needed for the class. The problem is, I can't do that, because `__init__` has to be synchronous.

Here is the relevant part of my code (edited for simplicity, the logic remains the same):

```
# This has to be called outside of the class
asyncDatabaseConnection = startDBConnection()

class discordBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Init is only run once, but we cant use async stuff here
        self.firstRun = True

    async def on_ready(self):
        # Other stuff happens here but it doesen't involve this question

        # on_ready is called when bot is ready, but can be called multiple times when running
        # (if bot has to reconnect to API), so we have to check
        if self.firstRun:
            await asyncDatabaseConnection.setValue("key", "value")
            self.firstRun = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Instance class and start async stuff
    bot = discordBot()
    bot.run()
```

As you can see, it is for a Discord bot, but that doesn't really matter, it's more about the logic.

The function I want to call is `asyncDatabaseConnection.setValue("key", "value")`.

Like I said, I cannot call it from `__init__` because `__init__` has to be synchronous, so instead I set `firstRun` to `True` during the init call, and then I can use that later on to tell if the code has been run before or not

`on_ready` is a function that is called when the bot is ready to start sending/receiving data, so I can use it as sort of a second `__init__`. The problem comes from the fact that `on_ready` can be called multiple times throughout the running of the program, meaning I have to have the `firstRun` check I described before.

This seems like a lot of code just to do 1 thing at startup (as well as adding overhead, however small, when `on_ready` is called). Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I would argue that you should have a function that does the async task and then synchronously initializes and returns an instance of the class.

Comment: duplicate of [How to set class attribute with await in \_\_init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128325/how-to-set-class-attribute-with-await-in-init). see also [Python: Defining a class with an async constructor (3 ways)](https://www.slingacademy.com/article/python-defining-a-class-with-an-async-constructor/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a little awkward, but you can [create a `Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks), then run it and get its result.  If you do this often, it may help to write a helper function:

```
def run_and_get(coro):
    task = asyncio.create_task(coro)
    asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete(task)
    return task.result()

class discordBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        run_and_get(asyncDatabaseConnection.setValue("key", "value"))
```

This depends on there being a running event loop, which I believe `Client.__init__` sets up

Comment: This seems like it might solve my problem. Why do you turn `coro` into a `Task`? Is it just to be able to get a return value? If I don't need a return value, can I just do `run_until_complete(coro)`?

Comment: I think if you do that it just creates a Task or Future for that coroutine under the hood, so there shouldn't be any performance implications.

Comment: I get This event loop is already running

Comment: @Hacker please create a [mre] and ask your own question.

Comment: > Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Hacker. The problem is that this code only works in code that's not called via async code, e.g. if `async def outer()` calls `def inner()`, and `inner()` tries calling `run_and_get()`, that's when the problem arises.

Comment: @paulie4 That's because the event loop is already blocking waiting on `outer`, and there's no way from inside `inner` to communicate that it should pause `outer` and execute whatever coroutine `run_and_get` wants to run. The short answer is to refactor. You need to segregate your code so that it's either all async or so that there's only an async shell that calls regular functions. I can't really give specific advice here without knowing exactly how your program is designed. Maybe `inner` should be returning tasks and then the caller can decide whether to `run_and_get` or `await`?