# Does a class __init__ method need to be async if working with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to write objects that then will be used doing asyncio tasks. The constructor of the class is as follow:

```py
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for a,b in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, a, b)  #dynamically sets values to parent class props
```

**My question is:**
When working with classes in async, is it needed to make everything in the class awaitable ?, doing such would need to write a lot more code since it is almost 1 `await` per line when accessing class props.
If the function can execute relatively fast (very light calculations like above) can I *leave* them sync ?

Comment: No, that is not necessary.

Comment: @KlausD. Can you explain why it is not necessary ?, because it is fully CPU bound ?

Comment: Imagine all code had to be async. You couldn't use more than 90% of the Python standard library with asyncio.

Comment: It isn’t possible to make `__init__` awaitable. Using `async def` makes a function return a coroutine and `__init__` must always return `None`.

Comment: @dirn Technically, it *is* possible to make `__init__` awaitable. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128325/how-to-set-class-attribute-with-await-in-init) for some ways to do it. Still, it's probably not a good idea, even if it is possible.